# OpenCL brute force TEA block 32bit, key 64bit

Tags: opencl

I decided to study OpenCL myself and write a brute-force password for the TEA algorithm, did I understand OpenCL correctly? can you improve something in the direction of speed? what mistakes have I made?

I prepare the first 5 bytes in cycles, the remaining 3 bytes are sorted out by the kernel, 255 threads at 65535 each

in the main program:

```
for (int x5 = KEY[0]; x5 >= 0; x5--) {
KEY[0]=x5;
for (int x4 = KEY[1]; x4 >= 0; x4--) {
KEY[1]=x4;
for (int x3 = KEY[2]; x3 >= 0; x3--) {
KEY[2]=x3;
for (int x2 = KEY[3]; x2 >= 0; x2--) {
KEY[3]=x2;
for (int x = KEY[4]; x >= 0; x--) {
KEY[4]=x;

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, key_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
8 * sizeof(int), KEY, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, cadr_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
1 * sizeof(int), CADR, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&key_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cadr_mem_obj);

NDRange = 0x0100;

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
&NDRange, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {

break;
}

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, cadr_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
1 * sizeof(int), CADR, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (CADR[0]>0) {

uint16_t k=CADR[0];

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, retc_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
524280 * sizeof(int), RETC, 0, NULL, NULL);


for ((i = 0); i < k; i++) {
Form1->Memo1->Lines->BeginUpdate();
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToHex(RETC[i*8],2)+IntToHex(RETC[i*8+1],2)+
IntToHex(RETC[i*8+2],2)+IntToHex(RETC[i*8+3],2)+IntToHex(RETC[i*8+4],2)+
IntToHex(RETC[i*8+5],2)+IntToHex(RETC[i*8+6],2)+IntToHex(RETC[i*8+7],2));
Form1->Memo1->Lines->EndUpdate();
    Form1->Label6->Caption=IntToStr(Form1->Memo1->Lines->Count-1);
}
CADR[0]=0;
}

KEY2[0]=KEY[0];
KEY2[1]=KEY[1];
KEY2[2]=KEY[2];
KEY2[3]=KEY[3];
KEY2[4]=KEY[4];
KEY2[5]=KEY[5];
KEY2[6]=KEY[6];
KEY2[7]=KEY[7];

if(Terminated){
break;
}
}
KEY[4]=0xFF;
}
KEY[3]=0xFF;
}
KEY[2]=0xFF;
}
KEY[1]=0xFF;
}
KEY[0]=0xFF;`
```

Kernel:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics : enable

__kernel void    brute(__global const int *KEY, __global const int *DAT, __global int 
*CADR,__global int *RETC)
{

int i = get_global_id(0);

ushort Data[2];
ushort Key[4];

Key[0]=(KEY[0]<<8)+KEY[1];
Key[1]=(KEY[2]<<8)+KEY[3];
// Key[2]=(KEY[4]<<8)+KEY[5];
Key[3]=(KEY[6]<<8)+KEY[7];

Key[2] = (KEY[4]<<8) + i;

for (int j=0xFFFF; j>=0; j--){

Key[3]=j;

Data[0]=(DAT[0]<<8)+DAT[1];
Data[1]=(DAT[2]<<8)+DAT[3];

 ushort delta = 0x9e37;
ushort sum = (delta<<5);

for (uint n = 0;n < 32; ++n){
Data[1]-=(((Data[0])+Key[2])^(Data[0]+sum)^((Data[0]>>5)+Key[3]));
Data[0]-=(((Data[1]<<4)+Key[0])^(Data[1]+sum)^(Data[1]+Key[1]));
sum -= delta;
}

if ((Data[0]==0x0000) && (Data[1]==0x0000)){
int a=CADR[0];
atomic_inc(CADR);
RETC[a*8]=(Key[0] >> 8);
RETC[a*8+1]=(Key[0] & 0xFF);
RETC[a*8+2]=(Key[1] >> 8);
RETC[a*8+3]=(Key[1] & 0xFF);
RETC[a*8+4]=(Key[2] >> 8);
RETC[a*8+5]=(Key[2] & 0xFF);
RETC[a*8+6]=(Key[3] >> 8);
RETC[a*8+7]=(Key[3] & 0xFF);

}


}


}
```

Comment: this also depends very much on your hardware; Is that a question about your particular implementation (which we cannot test on your hardware) of about making a generic implementation (efficicient on any hardware)?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify about the threads, as I understood there are 256, 512 (each video card has its own), I chose the best option for writing code 256, this is KEY [5] 256 threads are simultaneously started and iterate over KEY [6] and KEY [7 ] = 65536 keys using a regular loop (I apologize if something is not written correctly, I use google translator)

Comment: I understand correctly if I do so, will I squeeze the maximum out of the video card? 
`size_t work_group_size;
clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &work_group_size, NULL);
NDRange = 0x010000;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,&NDRange, &work_group_size, 0, NULL, NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

If you only launch 256 threads that each do 65536 iterations of the same thing, your GPU will not be saturated and performance will be very poor. GPUs have thousands of "cores", and if you launch 256 threads you will only use 256 of them while the rest remains idle.

The idea of GPU parallelization is to split the work up into as many imdependent problems as there are. In your case this means: Lauch 256*65536 threads that do one Iteration each. Then performance will be much better.

Comment: Wouldn't I do the same when launching the kernel : 
 `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,65536, 256, 0, NULL, NULL);` ???